# Python generator function - is there an excel equivalent?

Tags: python, excel, generator

I'm looking to run through a large list of numbers in Excel, and need the programme to be as accessible as possible for other people.

I'd like to keep the spreadsheet Excel only (possibly VBA), but is there an equivalent of Python's generator, or yield functions available in Excel?

i.e.

```
gen = (x for x in range(10))
```

Comment: I seriously doubt that. I have not seen generators outside of python. In python 3 `range` is already a generator, so you only need to use `gen = range(10)`.

Comment: I have seen generators and coroutines in other languages, but definitely not VBA.

Comment: Thanks @TammoHeeren, I didn't actually know that, so that's a bonus find! ;)

Comment: Please describe what you want to do with the `gen` after it is generated. `Excel` can handle array functions and so `VBA` can also using evaluation.

Comment: Overall, I'm taking data from a website which lists standards sizes from components, and I'm pairing them with regular increments in size of bespoke components. I want to list every combination, and export it to an xml file to use with another piece of software.

Comment: It would be good if I could stick with Excel because the fewer types of file needed overall, the fewer things to go wrong ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments it would be good if you could exactly describe what you are trying to do in `Excel`.

`Excel` can perform array formulas. Within those array formulas we can use `ROW` or `COLUMN` function to get arrays of successive integers.

For example:

```
{=SUM(ROW(1:10))}
```

inputted as an array formula with [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] will calculate the sum of the integers from 1 to 10.

To input an array formula, input the formula into the cell without the curly brackests and then press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] to confirm. The curly brackets will then appear automatically.

Or with VBA:

```
Sub test()

 Dim gen As Variant

 gen = [{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}] 
 ' gen is now an Array Variant(1 to 10) containing integers 0 to 9

 gen = [ROW(1:10)-1] 
 ' gen is now an Array Variant(1 to 10, 1 to 1) containing integers 0 to 9

 For Each i In gen

  MsgBox i

 Next

 Erase gen ' free the memory used by gen

End Sub
```

will loop from 0 to 9.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I answered that comment. I think you've put what I'm after (I'm less experienced with VBA!). Does this work as a list, where the values stay in memory, or are the values deleted after being used? I'm  looking at generating values in increments of 10 between

Comment: 0 and 300, before pairing them with another list to generate all possible values. There'll be a lot of combinations, so by having the values delete after use, I should save computing time.

Comment: The `gen` is into memory until you are freeing the memory using `Erase gen`. Your answer to my comment was too broad. Please edit your question and describe the concrete problem. Btw..: Loop from 0 to 300 in step 10 sounds to me like a simple `For i = 0 to 300 Step 10 ... Next`.

Comment: Thanks for that. Sorry but I can't go into more detail than what I have.

Comment: As mentioned earlier, I'm not just looping through those increments, I've set up query tables to pull live data from websites, and these need to be combined. There are billions of combinations, so I'm looking at ways of reducing them.